# How to check if a string contains multiple other strings?

Tags: c++, string

I am very new to C++.

With a combination of Google and StackOverflow I have managed to write some code to check if a string contains another string.

```
string stringToSearch = "my foo bar";
std::string firstNeedle("foo");
std::size_t firstSearch = stringToSearch.find(firstNeedle);

if( firstSearch != std::string::npos ){
    // do code here
}
```

This code works brilliantly. However, now I want to add another string to look for, so something like....

```
string stringToSearch = "my foo bar";
std::string firstNeedle("foo");
std::size_t firstSearch = stringToSearch.find(firstNeedle);

std::string secondNeedle("bar");
std::size_t secondSearch = stringToSearch.find(secondNeedle);

if( (firstSearch != std::string::npos) || (secondSearch != std::string::npos) ){
    // do code here
}
```

I'm presuming this won't work as there is nothing to indicate which string the "std::string::npos" is referring to?

I wondered how I would do this?

Or is it possible to use an array - In PHP (because I'm familiar with PHP) something like:

```
$stringToSearch = "my foo bar";
$arrayOfSearchTerms = array("foo", "bar");

foreach( $arrayOfSearchTerms as $singleSearchTerm ){
    if( strpos( $stringToSearch, $singleSearchTerm ) !== false) {
        // do code here
    }
}
```

Comment: **Do not Pre-assume everything**, just try basic rule of debugging add print (cout for CPP) statements to know which part of code is causing problem.

Comment: `std::string::npos` is a `static const` member, so it is the same for any string.

Comment: you can read about **std::string::npos** here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/

Comment: @Fareanor yep, just had a massive lightbulb moment about that when I re-read my question and read Blaze's answer. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm presuming this won't work

This works just fine. The way you have it, the `// do code here` code will be executed if at least one of the strings was found, so if `"my foo bar"` contains either `"foo"` or `"bar"` or both of them.

If you want it so it only works if **both** `"foo"` and `"bar"` have to be contained in the `stringToSearch`, you can achieve that by changing the `||` to `&&`:

```
if ((firstSearch != std::string::npos) && (secondSearch != std::string::npos)) {
```

> as there is nothing to indicate which string the "std::string::npos"
>   is referring to?

Nah, there's no issue here. `(firstSearch != std::string::npos)` evaluates to a boolean value and `(secondSearch != std::string::npos)` evaluates to a separate boolean value that doesn't conflict with it in any way. You can use logical operators such as `&&` and `||` to work with those booleans as usual.

Comment: Wow... I've just re-read it and it makes perfect sense now! The npos value is contained within the firstSearch / secondSearch strings. Like an element of that variable (not sure of correct terminology here). That's brilliant. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly you can write

```
for ( const auto &s : { "foo", "bar" } )
{
    auto pos = stringToSearch.find( s );
    if ( pos != std::string::npos )
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

The same can be done using variables. For example

```
string stringToSearch = "my foo bar";
std::string firstNeedle("foo");
std::string secondNeedle("bar");

for ( const auto &s : { firstNeedle, secondNeedle } )
{
    auto pos = stringToSearch.find( s );
    if ( pos != std::string::npos )
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string stringToSearch = "my foo bar";
    std::string firstNeedle("foo");
    std::string secondNeedle("bar");

    for ( const auto &s : { firstNeedle, secondNeedle } )
    {
        auto pos = stringToSearch.find( s );
        if ( pos != std::string::npos )
        {
            std::cout << stringToSearch.substr( pos ) << '\n';
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```